# Lateral Shifting of a ray in YDSE experiment when a slab is inserted in after a slit

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment

I was studying YDSE. It was a topic where a glass slab was inserted just after a slit.

- Does lateral Shifting takes place?
- If it takes place then why does the ray go straight as shown in image below?

I got no clue about it on the internet therefore, came to SE.
For reference please consider the given image.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let’s assume that without the slab with refractive index $n_3$ there are equal numbers of wavelengths between the two slits and point $O$ on the screen.
This will mean that there will be a bright fringe at position $O$.

Introducing the slab with refractive index $n_3$ will result in the wavelength of the waves in the slab to be shorter than they were previously if $n_3>n_2$.

So now there are not the same number of wavelengths in the paths from the two slits to point $O$ and there will not necessarily be a bright fringe at $O$ unless the slab introduces an integer number of wavelengths.

So the zeroth order bright fringe which results from equal number of wavelengths in the two paths will move to being above point $O$ and the rest if the fringe pattern will do the same.
This what you have termed *lateral shifting* of the fringe pattern.

Comment: Sir, This means the diagram is misleading in the question?

Comment: @user12076043 No, because there will be light which travels along the path of the rays.